# Dress in / Dress with / Dress up

Tags: prepositions

Guests invited to the Merrills' 20th wedding anniversary celebration are expected to dress _____ formal attire.

1. in
2. with
3. on
4. per

I have never asked question but when i was studying something this thing came out and made me blurred.

What's the correct answer? is it something to do with idiomatic pattern that 
when you use the word dress, the stable preposition should come along all the time?

Thanks

Comment: I *love* your expression "made me blurred", can I steal it? Usually people say "it confused me" or for added drama  "it stopped me in my tracks". Some will tell you your expression is wrong, and to a certain extent they may be right, but "it made me blurred" is simply delightful.

Comment: If you can answer this correctly, you have your answer: *Are you dressed* (a) with a t-shirt / (b) in a t-shirt / (c) on a t-shirt / (d) per a t-shirt? Which ones are obviously wrong? Which ones sound wrong, are you undecided between two options? Can you explain "why"?

Comment: Your title has **"dress up"** but none of the options include that expression. Please edit either the question or the title because it *is* a little confusing.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, So when i should say 'dress up' in this sentence, is it correct if i use 'dress up in formal attire'?

Comment: The multiple question does not include "dress up". Is this one of the options in the "test question"; yes or no? Are you confused about ALL the four options; yes or no? Have you looked in a dictionary to try and answer this question? Did you understand that my second comment is worded as to help you reach the "correct" answer to *this* question. If you do not understand my second comment, then this is the wrong website for you. May I recommend EL&U's sister-site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Mari-Lou A What's the point of going to other website in search of my answer? Is the theme different or the question being asked is simply labeled elementary so it dare not to be asked here? I looked into the dictionary but i guess it has very various meaning and usage so i was wondering if i could find a correct concept to this. I understand dress with should be something to describe the object of what subject is wearing like 'She's wearing a dress with a pattern of tiny roses' when Dress in should sound "You must dress in a black gown and pick up your cap." Pls help

Comment: Congratulations! You have eliminated numbers 3 and 4. You now have your answer, compare: "wearing a dress" and " you must dress" Which one is the verb "to dress" and which is the noun "a dress"?

Comment: Your question has the infinitive verb **"to dress"**.

Comment: infinitive verb "to dress" jack pot. Thanks a lot!